# Center a Div with dynamical height/width

Tags: html, css, center

i built a little site, in which I load content via ajax and jquery, when a link in my nav-section is clicked. The content is loaded into a div called "content". Now I want to center this div that everything is in the middle of my page. I know how to do that with `margin: 0 auto;`, but this only works when a width is set to it.

This is the div I want to center:

```
<!--CONTENT-->
<div id="container" class="content"></div>
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qnh5/

Also, the logout button should be displayed on the left side of my footer. How can I make this happen?

```
<!-- LOGOUT BUTTON -->
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <button class="button-logout" name="Ausloggen">Logout</button>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I didn't understand the question... Why you don't just use width=100% in your container div? <div id="container" class="content" width="100%"></div>

Comment: can I just set the div to 100% width and then use the `margin: 0 auto;`? Sorry, I'm new to css and found that header tutorial on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
.content {
    padding: 2em 5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Didn't know that it was that easy! Do you also have a solution for my second question (Button on the left of my footer)?

Comment: In the jsfiddle its on the left in the footer... I also don't see body and footer declarations in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I meant right.The declaration is the `<div id="footer1">`and the body is `<div id="content">`

Comment: ok I solved it! Used `float: right;`and set  `margin: auto;`. Thanks though!!

Comment: `float:right;` in the `.button-logout` should work but its actin buggy . Edit: Ahh nice!